# C# Remove property and inner property from Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

If I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "A": 1,
  "B": 2,
  "E": {
    "X": true,
    "Y": true
  }
}
```

I want to remove `B` property and inside `E` remove `X` using [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

So I want to have this:

```
{
  "A": 1,
  "E": {
    "Y": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JObject.Remove(propertyName)`, and for inner properties you will need to cast the `JToken?` to `JObject`

For example:

object

```
object obj = new
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    E = new
    {
        X = true,
        Y = true
    }
};

JObject jObj = JObject.FromObject(obj);
```

remove

```
jObj.Remove("B");
((JObject)jObj["E"]).Remove("X");
```

print the object json

```
Console.WriteLine(jObj.ToString());
```

json string

```
{
  "A": 1,
  "E": {
    "Y": true
  }
}
```